# Actionscript 3 Dynamic line drawing with changing alpha

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have been creating a training tool for a customer in Flash, using Actionscript 3. In it i have to create one continuous line generated over time, whose alpha is controlled by a static object and its distance from a continuous moving object.  The closer the two are, the stronger the line, the further the weaker.  This alpha only effects the the line at the current time, leaving the historical alpha as it was when the the line was produced. The way I have currently made it is by generating lots of small lines, which when joined together make one big line.  Thus each small line has a different alpha.  The overall effect is to create fade ins and outs based on the distance between the two objects with historical alpha still showing. Does anyone out there have a better way of achieving this effect?  Hopefully,  I have not just confused everybody.

Comment: What problem do you have with your current solution? If you want to have your code reviewed and improved, ask for that at [codereview.se]. If you ask a question there, you obviously have to include the working code that you have right now.

Comment: "better" is subjective.  Do you mean more efficient? Do you mean programatically easier to understand?  Do you mean visually smoother transitions of alpha values?

Comment: As I read it a second time, I would say your approach is "correct"

Comment: I dont get what effects you try to achieve. Some pictures could be handy. Also, Flash has some limits when it comes to draw objects with alpha on top of each other, so you might end with a garbled display.